# Changing css class name does not change style

Tags: css, smartgwt

I am working with smartgwt and css. I have different blocks. when a block is focused I change the style name of the block and blur the other blocks.

Everything works correctly except that sometimes when I change block focus two blocks become active (highlighted). It's weird because when I verify the css class through the inspector the inactive block has not the "active" class.

It means that the css style has not rendered correctly. Is that a common problem? Is there a possibility to refresh the rendering of an html element after updating its class name?

```
.windowFocused {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-color: #50A9CC !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 0 0 0 #50A9CC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 0 0 0 #50A9CC;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 0 0 #50A9CC;
}
```

I add this class when focused and remove it on blur. When I check the page through the inspector it is correctly removed but it keeps the style.

Comment: You're going to need, at the very least, show us the CSS and associated html if you're hoping to get some help :)

Comment: kindly add a fiddle link for better understanding of the problem.